# link_to, view, controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, link-to

I implemented this link:

View:

```
<li><%= link_to "Trainer-Sportler", :controller => "trainerones", :action => "trspmatch" %></li>
```

controller:

```
def trspmatch
   render :trspmatch
end
```

and one view trspmatch.html.erb

Rails says:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for TraineronesController
```

When i implemented def show end and create a show.html.erb. Rails opens the show.html.erb not the trspmatch.html.erb?

Comment: Show us your routes.rb file so we can help

Comment: the important part of my routes.rb:

Comment: resources :trainerones do
    get "trainerones/index"
    get "trainerones/trspmatch"
    get "trainerones/imports"
  end

  resources :sportlers do
    get "sportlers/index"
  end

  resources :administrators do
    get "administrators/index"
  end

  resources :people do
    get :check_valid, on: :member
    get :save_formular, on: :member
    get :make_paars, on: :member
    
    resources :orts
    resources :trainingseinheits
    resources :photos
    resources :plans
    resources :tagebuches
  end

Comment: match 'people/trspmatch/check_valid' => 'people#check_valid'
  match 'people/make_paars' => 'people#make_paars'
  match 'people/save_formular' => 'people#save_formular'
  match 'trainerones/trspmatch' => 'trainerones#trspmatch'
  match 'trainerones/new' => 'trainerones#new'
  match 'trainerones/imports' => 'trainerones#imports'

Comment: Perhaps better if you show that in your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to define your trainerones resource like this:

```
resources :trainerones do
   collection do
     get 'trspmatch'
   end
end
```

that will expose a url /trainerones/trspmatch that maps to TraineronesController#trspmatch. It seems that a look at [this link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) will help you understand routes better.

In any case, you will benefit a lot from running `rake routes` in your console, which will display all your routes and how they map to your controllers methods. Try before and after rewriting your trainerones resource as I explained above, and you'll see the difference. Good luck!